# Why has my GTA Online character suddenly got a hand tattoo?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I loaded up *GTA Online* and since this morning when I was playing, my character’s developed a yin and yang tattoo on his hand. Why and where has this come from?

Answer (score -1):

If you have another person in your household that plays on your account,they most likely have added it.You can get it removed,but not refunded.Hope this helps.

Comment: Not the problem.